# FInding associated values from same column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find assosiate sid for each sid.
I was trying with self join but could not find the count for sid linked with associated sid.

Data :

```
gid sid
g1  s1
g1  s2
g2  s2
g2  s3
g2  s4
g3  s1
g3  s3
g4  s2
g4  s3
g4  s4
g2  s2
```

Expected Output:

```
sid associated_sid  freq of sid occuring with other sid
s1  s2              1
s1  s3              1
s2  s1              1
s2  s3, s3          2
s2  s4, s4          2
s3  s1              1
s3  s2, s2          2
s3  s4, s4          2
s4  s2, s2          2
s4  s3, s3          2
```

Comment: By "associated" do you mean one or more SID values appears with the same GID value? Also, is this for MySQL or Snowflake? You have both tags.

Comment: yes but not with same GID value, associated sid can be with any GID value

Comment: Is the last row of your sample data (g2, s2) correct which would mean that there are duplicate pairs?

Comment: yes there can be duplicate pairs @forpas

Comment: Why for s2  s3 is the freq=1?

Comment: my bad it was mistake, edited the data

Comment: Why there is no row for s2,s4 in your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self join and aggregation with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT t1.sid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.sid) associated_sid,
       COUNT(*) freq
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT gid, sid FROM tablename) t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT gid, sid FROM tablename) t2
ON t2.gid = t1.gid AND t2.sid <> t1.sid
GROUP BY t1.sid, t2.sid
ORDER BY t1.sid, t2.sid;
```

Or, with a CTE (MySql version 8.0+):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT gid, sid FROM tablename)
SELECT t1.sid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.sid) associated_sid,
       COUNT(*) freq
FROM cte t1 INNER JOIN cte t2
ON t2.gid = t1.gid AND t2.sid <> t1.sid
GROUP BY t1.sid, t2.sid
ORDER BY t1.sid, t2.sid;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f9046ace1b2aa477e23d2e8a9399821).

Comment: what if i don't want the duplicate in output like these should give either of them

s3  s4, s4          2  |
s4  s3, s3          2

Comment: @loving_guy change `t2.sid <> t1.sid` to `t2.sid > t1.sid`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it would be great if you could please also explain how the query is being executed and how the results are achieved as expected

Answer (score 1):

You are linking relations in two levels max. A more generic query can be done for three or more levels, but the following one works for two:

```
with
r as (
  select a.gid, a.sid, b.sid as aid
  from data a join data b on b.gid = a.gid and a.sid <> b.sid
),
c as (
  select x.*, y.gid as rgid from r x
  left join r y on y.gid <> x.gid and x.sid = y.sid and x.aid = y.aid
),
e as (
  select distinct *
  from c 
  where rgid is not null or rgid is null and not exists (
    select 1 from c d where d.sid = c.sid and d.aid = c.aid and rgid is not null
  )
)
select sid, group_concat(aid) as associated_sid, count(*) as freq
from e
group by sid, aid
order by sid, aid
```

Result:

```
 sid  associated_sid  freq 
 ---- --------------- ---- 
 s1   s2              1    
 s1   s3              1    
 s2   s1              1    
 s2   s3,s3           2    
 s2   s4,s4           2    
 s3   s1              1    
 s3   s2,s2           2    
 s3   s4,s4           2    
 s4   s2,s2           2    
 s4   s3,s3           2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82faafa6904e4c321b9489af09280522).

Comment: Thanks but could you please also explain what is going on in the query?